# laravel 4 reset password link missing mandatory param

Tags: php, laravel, passwords

I'm running into some tricky errors with password reset functionality. I'm using Laravel 4.0.9 and, while the password email and reminder function works just fine, I always get the following error message when I click on the email link:

**Some mandatory parameters are missing ("token") to generate a URL for route "post /password/reset/{token}".**

The url I'm going to is http://{my server}/password/reset/{token}

The relevant lines in my route.php file are as follows:

```
Route::post('/password/reset/{token}', 'RemindersController@postReset');

Route::get('/password/reset/{token}', 'RemindersController@getReset');
```

And finally, here is the function in my controller:

```
/**
 * Display the password reset view for the given token.
 *
 * @param  string  $token
 * @return Response
 */
public function getReset($token = null)
{
    if (is_null($token)) {
        App::abort(404);
    }

    return View::make('password.reset')->with('token', $token);
}
```

This all seems to follow the standard docs to the letter and I am certainly sending along a "token" variable. Can anyone guess what might be going wrong here?

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 0):

Alas, there was a problem with the form in the view that was eventually loaded. This is all correct, I just need to fix the form.